# MAUI Android apk will not run if downloaded from webste

Tags: maui

I know the normal rule is to include source code, but I know that's not the problem, because the Welcome to Maui app that gets generated on Create New Project doesn't even work.
Tell me what you want to see, and I'll gladly add it.

I have a MAUI app that works fine when I deploy it to my Android 12 phone from Visual Studio 2022, but when I build the apk and put it on my company's internal website for the QA department to download, it crashes on launch immediately after the splash screen appears.
I have generated keystore files over and over, searched git and stackoverflow and just about every other corner of the web that I can think of, but the apk simply won't run if it's downloaded and installed. It downloads and installs just fine, but it crashes on launch.
I have even tried starting fresh with a new project that only has the initial code generated by Visual Studio. It also downloads and installs, but crashes on launch, and my phone says "MauiApp1 closed because this app has a bug."

I can make Xamarin apps all day and they work just fine.

Does anybody have any ideas?

I since found a logcat viewer extension:

```
02-07 06:47:14.897 E/pageboostd( 2845): alp start : app commyappmobile
02-07 06:47:14.898 E/pageboostd( 2845): commyappmobile, amt 0 scnt 0 fcnt 0
02-07 06:47:14.898 E/pageboostd( 2845): commyappmobile, amt 0 scnt 0 fcnt 0
02-07 06:47:14.898 E/pageboostd( 2845): alp end : app comjettyappmobiledist data_amount 0
02-07 06:47:14.899 E/ActivityTaskManager( 1423): TouchDown intent received, starting ActiveLaunch
02-07 06:47:14.906 E/libprocessgroup( 1423): Failed to write '6-7' to /dev/cpuset/system-background/cpus: Permission denied
02-07 06:47:14.954 E/libprocessgroup( 1423): Failed to write '0-5' to /dev/cpuset/system-background/cpus: Permission denied
02-07 06:47:14.956 E/USNET   (12431): USNET: appName: com.myapp.mobile
02-07 06:47:14.960 E/libprocessgroup( 1423): Failed to write '0-5' to /dev/cpuset/system-background/cpus: Permission denied
02-07 06:47:14.977 E/BufferQueueDebug(  905): [Splash Screen com.myapp.mobile$_1814#0](this:0xe9d3fda4,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'Splash Screen com.jettyapp.mobile.dist$_1814#0'
02-07 06:47:14.995 E/pageboostd( 2845): Received HALT command code 2
```

Comment: Have you tried logging? You can use logcat with attached devices even for APKs that you installed manually on your device. Also, in these situations the problem often is the linker behavior. When creating the APK in Release mode, try using the option "Link SDK Assemblies" or "Do not link" to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Have you looked at the device logs?  Have you installed any crash reporting on logging tools?  Are you using the same profile when testing locally and when deploying to other devices?  You can deploy for free using AppCenter.ms which also includes crash reporting tools.

Comment: You've tested deploying `Release` build from VS?

Comment: I have added logcat output to the question.

Comment: @JohnUreke Did you try what ToolmakerSteve asked? The logcat output points to the Splash Screen. Can you show how that's set up in your MAUI project? Usually that would be in the *.csproj* file using the `<MauiSplashScreen>` build action.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Release build worked. Now I have to find out what's wrong with my QA configuration. They need to point to different servers for their APIs. At least something works now!